# Get label with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, label

I have a nested form and I would like to apply some Javascript on it :

```
<label for="order_payments_attributes_1362416152585_Date :">Date :</label>
<input id="order_payments_attributes_1362416152585_date" type="text" size="7" name="order[payments_attributes][1362416152585][date]">
```

As it is not possible for me to add a static id (because as it is a nested form, id are dynamic), how can I get the label and hide it with javascript for example ? I am able to change the input with its ID but not the label...

Thanks for your help, I am trying to finish this point since this morning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can target the `input` by it's id, targeting the label should be possible since it's `for` attribute should match the input's id.

Using jQuery, you can match it like this:

```
$('label[for=order_payments_attributes_1362416152585_date]')
```

and to hide it you can simply call `.hide()` on the above selector

```
$('label[for=order_payments_attributes_1362416152585_date]').hide();
```

It looks like you're doing something wrong when generating the field/label, because your label's `for` attribute should not appear as `order_payments_attributes_1362416152585_Date :`. Here, the `Date :` portion looks wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this but it seems that it was a " ' " missing or something like that...